# How to tell if your select query is within a transaction or not?

Tags: django, django-orm

In Django 1.5.x, I have a long running management command where select queries are returning stale data. I suspect this is due to the fact that they are running within a transaction that are started earlier on the db connnection. Is there a way a tell if a query runs within a transaction or it is in autocommit mode?

(this is somewhat more focused version of an earlier question I posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18540099/orm-does-not-return-recent-database-changes)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since Django 1.7, `Connection.in_atomic_block` will tell you if a connection is inside a transaction or not. It doesn't seem like this is documented, but it Works On My Machine:

```
from django.db import transaction
cxn = transaction.get_connection()
if cxn.in_atomic_block:
    print "We're inside a transaction!"
```

Comment: This is the test that Django itself uses to control flow, which is the best that you're going to get when digging up a solution via the source https://github.com/django/django/blob/074a2f7f58cfab807ae72b09e634cad30a895369/django/db/backends/base/base.py#L423-L425

Comment: I think there are other ways besides `transaction.atomic()` to be in a transaction, that this approach would miss.

Comment: One thing to note:  `TestCase` handles cleanup by using transactions and rolling back.  This means code that may normally not see a transaction will see a transaction when run through a test case.

Comment: `TransactionTestCase` can be used instead (which is slower, but doesn't use transactions).

Answer (score 4):

Since Django 1.6 you can tell if you're in autocommit mode via [transaction.get_autocommit](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.get_autocommit) API.

```
from django.db import transaction

if transaction.get_autocommit():
    pass  # We are in autocommit
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if you are in a transaction by checking `is_managed`

```
if transaction.is_managed():
    print "tutsi frutsi!"
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/ is_manged() will be removed in django 1.8. Unfortunately an alternative is unknown: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21004