# Check for atomic context

Tags: python, django, django-models, transactions, django-database

One of my methods doesn't work when run on atomic context. I want to ask Django if it's running a transaction.

The method can create a thread or a process and saves the result to database. This is a bit odd but there is a huge performance benefit when a process can be used.

I find that especially processes are a bit sketchy with Django. I know that Django will raise an exception if the method chooses to save the results in a process and the method is run on atomic context.

If I can check for an atomic context then I can throw an exception straight away (instead of getting odd errors) or force the method to only create a thread.

I found the `is_managed()` method but according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544033/how-to-tell-if-your-select-query-is-within-a-transaction-or-not) it's been removed in Django 1.8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21004) there are a couple ways to detect this: `not transaction.get_autocommit()` (using a public API) or `transaction.get_connection().in_atomic_block` (using a private API).

Comment: Whoops, I eyeballed the ticket but stopped reading it after the comment #2.